# C++ instantiate class inside a class with ctor parameters

Tags: c++, class

I have a problem with instantiating a class as a member of another class.
Here is my code:

```
class myClassA{
public:
    myClassA(){
        printf("myClassTwo ctor");
    }
    void doSomething(){ printf("myClassA did something\r\n");}
};

class myClassB{
public:
    myClassB(int i){
        printf("myClassA ctor got %d\r\n",i);
        threeMyI = i;
    }
private:
    int threeMyI;
};

class myClassC{
public:
    myClassC(){
        printf("C ctor without params\r\n");

    }
    myClassA instanceA;
    myClassB instanceB(29); //<== Not working why??

};
```

I have a class `myClassC` which I want to have two members, one of type `myClassA` and one `myClassB`. This works well for `myClassA`. But as soon as I try to create an instance of `myClassB`, which has an ctor parameter, it fails with the following compiler error:

```
..\src\main.cpp:34:21: error: expected identifier before numeric constant   
myClassB instanceB(29); //<== Not working why??
..\src\main.cpp:34:21: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

In my main function this type of declaration works well:

```
int main(void){

    printf("class test\r\n");
    myClassC instanceC1;

    myClassA instanceA1;
    myClassB instanceB1(25);

    return 0;
}
```

But I have no idea what makes the big difference when instantiating a class with ctor parameters. Hope somebody can give me an hint what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `myClassB instanceB(29); //<== Not working why??` You need to do the initialization in the member initializer list of the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only *declare* member variables, you cannot instantiate them.

To invoke the constructor of a member-variable you can use the memberwise initialization paradigm in your own constructors:

```
struct A { // same as class A but public by default
    int m_a;

    A(int a) : m_a(a) {}
};

struct B {
    A m_a;
    int m_b;

    B(int a, int b) : m_a(a), m_b(b) {}
};
```

Or using your code:

```
#include <cstdio>


class myClassA{
public:
    myClassA(){
        printf("myClassTwo ctor");
    }
    void doSomething(){ printf("myClassA did something\r\n");}
};

class myClassB{
public:
    myClassB(int i) : threeMyI(i) {
        printf("myClassA ctor got %d\r\n",i);
    }
private:
    int threeMyI;
};

class myClassC{
public:
    myClassC() : instanceA(), instanceB(20) {
        printf("C ctor without params\r\n");

    }
    myClassA instanceA;
    myClassB instanceB;

};

int main()
{
    myClassA a;
    myClassB b(10);
    myClassC c;
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/G2aujC)

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understand, it seems that you want to use a default instantiation for your private attribute `instanceB`. In that case, what you are proposing is not legal, default input parameters should be set as followed

```
myClassC() : instanceB(29) { // mind the ":" character 
    printf("C ctor without params\r\n");
}
```

This will have the effect to call the constructor of `myClassB` to instantiate your private attribute `instanceB` with relevant default parameter.